# MediaStore check if file exist (even if pending or another package)

Tags: java, android, mediastore

Is there a way to check if an uri is avaiblable to be written? So need a way to check if a file exist even if it is pending or do not belong to my app package name?

if you do this:

```
Cursor cursor = resolver.query(mediaUri, Column, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME + "=?", new String[]{fileFullName}, null);
```

The problem is if the file is pending or do not belong to your package, the answer will be that the file doesn't exist. And then if you use resolver.insert it will failed because the file exist but is pending or something else.

If you add a syntax error in your query, you can see :

```
near ".": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT _id, _display_name FROM images WHERE ((owner_package_name IN ( 'xxxxx' )) AND (is_pending=0) AND (is_trashed=0) AND (volume_name IN ( 'external_primary' , '0ff0-0909' ))) AND (_display_name=.?)
```

So under the hood, ((owner_package_name IN ( 'xxxxx' )) AND (is_pending=0) is automatically added.

So how can we check if the file we want to create is available without runny in loop insert until it not failed ?

ps: I create a file "file.png". Then when i create a second one, the user can decide to overwrite or create a new one --> file(1).png (automatically added (1) inside the file name)

so I have an unknown possible file(xxx).png
I query and find the last one to add +1 to the number. it works as long as the file is not pending and belong to my app.
But since maybe the file is in pending or do not belong to my package, it not 99.9% i have the last one and i need to loop and insert util it not failed....

Hope, I succeed to make myself understand ;)

Comment: I wonder which use case you have that the file you are looking for is in pending state.

Comment: `(automatically added (1) inside the file name)` Yes. `find the last one to add +1 to the number.` If it is automatically then why would you add a number?

Comment: `how can we check if the file we want to create is available` Do you mean how to check if the file already exists?

Comment: - automatically add by me... so I need to be able to find the last one. so my ask...
- i mean exactly what i wrote :) MediaStore changed the game. If you do a query and get answer, it doesn't mean there is nothing. The file can be in pending state.

Answer (score 0):

So start of solution:

add and request this permission : android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Once you have the permission, the query do not automatically add under the hood (owner_package_name IN ( 'xxxxx' ) and so you really get a list of everything whatever the package.

But there is still under the hood (is_pending=0) add to your query. I still didn't find how to make a query whatever the pending state in order to check the file name available.